Gas Furnace Aux Heat not starting after 38MURA installation
I'm experiencing an issue with aux heat not working, but both the heat and cool heat pump functionality is working fine.  The equipment in play is:

Ecobee by Bryant Smart Thermostat
38MURA Bryant Heat Pump
Amana AMVC96 Gas Furnace

Wiring:

Thermostat -> Furnace
Rc -> R (outdoor unit also tied in with wire nut)
G -> G
C -> C (outdoor unit also tied in with wire nut)
Y1 -> Y2 (outdoor unit also tied in with wire nut)
W1 -> W2 (outdoor unit also tied in with wire nut)
OB on thermostat to outdoor unit, not tied in to furnace at all.

Should the Furnace Y and W connections be on Y1 and W1, instead of Y2 and W2, respectively?  I'll note that the cooling has functioned as intended all summer, and heat pump heat has also worked properly for about a week since I enabled it.  It is only the Aux Heat / gas furnace is failing to start now that the outdoor temp is lower than the threshold temp in the thermostat.
I do hear an audible hum from the furnace control board area when the call for Aux heat occurs, but that's it.  The inducer motor does not start, and best I can tell the gas furnace doesn't begin to start.




Working Solution
For anyone else experiencing the same issue, I spoke with the installation tech, and we determined that the Furnace W2 connection should be on W1 instead.  Everything else was good.
After making the switch, I confirmed that all is working, and I can get both heat pump heat and Aux heat as requested by the thermostat.
